How to add multiple emails in vbcs object trigger?
How to add multiple email to object trigger in visual builder cloud studio?
I can add single recipient or single variable. I need to add multiple email in a same email, so that i can see to whom are all the email is sending.

You should be able to use comma separated list of email addresses in the recipients field. Also if you switch to code view you'll see where to update this:
eMailNotification_1: {
def variables = [:];
Email.send('jow@oracle.com, mike@google.com', "nobody@oracle.com", "undefined", variables);
};
So you can use a groovy script to construct the emails.
